# Как сослаться на объект функции из другой функции в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть функция:

```
def open():
  folder_selected = (filedialog.askopenfilename())
  if folder_selected != '':
    f = pygame.mixer.music.load(folder_selected)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    print("vol", pygame.mixer.music.get_volume())
    duration = eyed3.load(folder_selected).info.time_secs
    print(duration)
    return duration
```

Мне надо сослаться на объект "duration" в другой функции:

```
def p(open):
  time = duration / 600
  i = 0
  s = 0
  for _ in range(time, time * 600, time):
    if value == i:
    pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(s)
  i = i + 1
  s = s + 1
```

Как это сделать?
Когда я пытаюсь выводит сообщение "name duration is not defined" Что делать?

Comment: Не стоит использовать имя 'open' - это зарезервированное слово.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в вашу функцию `p` следующую строку `duration=open()`. Должно получится так:

```
def p(open):
    duration=open()
    ...# ваш код
```

Comment: Появилась другая ошибка "duration = open() TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Comment: @DanilkaShcolnik покажите как вы вызывали `p`

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, нужно было добавить в функцию P строку "duration = open" без скобочек.
Всем спасибо)